# Puppet not executing catalogs

Tags: puppet

So I have this issue wherein my puppet master generates a catalog, this catalog is sent to the server which then runs it, but then nothing happens.

I did a printout with:

```
puppet master --verbose --compile billyjean > derp

  {
    "tags": ["class","file","authorized_keys","node","billyjean"],
    "type": "File",
    "parameters": {
      "source": "puppet:///modules/basetoolkit/ssh/authorized_keys",
      "ensure": "file",
      "path": "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys",
      "require": "File[sshfolder]"
    },
    "exported": false,
    "file": "/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp",
    "title": "authorized_keys",
    "line": 122
  },
```

So I am expecting it to copy my authkeys to the machine from location "modules/files/basetoolkit/ssh/authorized_keys" to the server, but nothing happens. It also seems there are other things that are not being run, but for now I am testing with this as it is the most non-critical.

Comment: Try running `puppet agent -t --debug`. Maybe it'll give you some clues. Also, there's a [type](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#sshauthorizedkey) for ssh keys.

Comment: Already tried that, nothing. And I am well aware of that, there is a reason I am not using it.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could share output when `--verbose` or `--evaltrace` are in use.

Comment: Doesn't help much, I'm afraid, only the main class is included in the catalog. The only way I seem to be able to get it to run any other code, is to include it directly in it's node in the site.pp file.

Comment: Can we see the manifest that won't work then?

Comment: I seems to have found the issue, but am still investigating, for some reason inheritances are not working at all on the agents. So I decided to pretty much strip them all out, but have now run into some other minor problems.

Comment: Thanks btw for the --evaltrace, that thing is magic for solving most of the other problems I had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have worked to remove inheritances and other stuff that is deprecated or marked as "don't use", but for some reason still in most of the manual:
http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_node_definitions.html#inheritance

Comment: As long as features are in the deprecation phase, they need to be covered by the reference manuals. When they are removed (Puppet 4 will include many removals of that sort), they need no longer be documented.

Comment: But inheritance and imports are still covered by the manual, even though imports will be removed by puppet 4 and inheritance will possibly be put in deprecated.

Comment: Removed features will not be part of the Puppet 4 reference documentation. They will (have to) remain in the Puppet 3 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

On the client check

```
/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml
```

There is probably some problem with the code you are attempting to apply on the client
By carefully reading this quite verbose file you should see a clue to what the problem is

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong in that file, except the lack of the before mentioned manifests appearing.